# Getting user attribute in sign in flow in Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

When I read the documentation from Microsoft for Azure B2C, it mentions that we can collect user attributes during the sign up flow.

I have a requirement where I need to get a input from the user during the sign in flow. Other than the username and password entered during the sign in, I need the user to enter another field.

Is there an option to do the above in the sign in flow?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-overview).

It will allow you to add any extra pages and/or logic to any journey.

Samples: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples

Comment: I could not find an example on how to create a custom policy to accept custom input during sign in. Can you please share a link to an example?

Comment: This [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/split-email-verification-and-signup) shows how to present more pages to the user by using the self asserted technical profile.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of collecting user input (eg. an additional field in the sign-up form) during sign-up without using custom policies is as follows:

- In the Azure B2C set up an additional *User Attribute* of the type *String*
- In the specific sign-in flow require this *User Attribute* to be collected.
- If needed, you can customize the wording and default values used in the form by supplying a language override in the specific flow.

Comment: When i try to create a userflow, it only allows to add user attributes to the signup screen. It specifically mentions that to select the user attributes that you need during the sign up. Do you have any reference on how to add it to sign in?

Comment: you are correct, I use it to get additional fields during sign up. Probably the only answer during sign-in is to use the Azure custom policies.