# Additional user input in B2C signin custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, aad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c

I want to, during the **sign in** flow, ask the user for additional input, which would be used as an inputClaim in one of the next steps of the user journey in a custom policy. The value does not need to be persisted. Ideally, it would be done in the sign-in window, but also could be collected from a separate window.

I am able to modify the sign-up window in this way, though not the sign-in one. Looked up in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy, but this again describes only the sign-up scenario.

There is a similar question asked by @Zzehan-jurangpathy here [Getting user attribute in sign in flow in Azure B2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68328928/getting-user-attribute-in-sign-in-flow-in-azure-b2c), though no answer that would actually be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the standard sign-in flow. It just allows username and password.

You can add an extra page by adding a self-asserted technical profile e.g. [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/upskilling-on-azure-b2c-custom-policies-adding-a-new-page-to-the-journey-1e66aeadbff3).